# JSON exception while parsing string from CloudMQTT

Tags: android, json

I am trying to parse JSON received from a MQTT broker, and display it into a recycler view, but I keep getting an exception while trying to create a JSON object. Why is this problem occurring, and what do I need to do to resolve it?

```
 public void messageArrived(String topic, MqttMessage mqttMessage)  {
            progressDialog.dismiss();

            Log.w("Debug", mqttMessage.toString());
            json_string = mqttMessage.toString();

            try {
                jsonObject = new JSONObject(json_string); //Problem Here?
                jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("message");

                for (int i =0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject o = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    List_Item item = new List_Item(
                            o.getString("subject"),
                            o.getString("body")
                    );
                    listItems.add(item);
                }
                adapter = new MyAdapter(listItems, getApplicationContext());
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Here's a copy of the JSON I was sending to the app:

```
    {“message”:[{“subject”:”Test 1”, “body”:”This is a Test.”},{“subject”:”Test 2”, “body”:”This is a Test.”},{“subject”:”Test 3”, “body”:”This is a Test.”},{“subject”:”Test 4”, “body”:”This is a Test.”}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is nothing but the quotes. The given example has `“` and `”` instead of `"`.

Comment: Can you explain the difference? Also, when I created the JSON I typed it  in Microsoft Word. How do I create the set of quotes that you suggested instead of the default ones?

Comment: JSON use quotation mark (U+0022) where as in the given example you are using left (U+201C) and right(U+201D) double quotation marks. The one i'm suggested is the same one present in the standard keyboard. In MS Word, you can simply find and replace.

Comment: I made the correction; unfortunately, there is still an exception. Do you have any more ideas about what the problem could be?

Comment: @Jordan Best not to use MS Word (or any word processor) for coding stuff.  Use a text editor such as Notepad++ and you won't get goofy stuff like smart quotes.

Comment: I used notepad++ and the problem has been resolved. I believe the issue was with the quotations, and possibly the commas. Thank you both so much for the advice.